# How can I use information from a ant script into java? (Android)

Tags: java, android, ant, build

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to pass ant variables to java code (android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843098/is-there-a-way-to-pass-ant-variables-to-java-code-android)

I have a automatic build system that build my applications by running ant build scripts. I want  to use a variable that I have in ant (for example a build number) in java. I want to display the build number for example to the user.

Does anybody knows how to do this or have a example (ant and java)?

Answer (score 1):

I typically use the ant variable to generate a new java constants class or a generate a properties file and access that from my java application. Either work depending on how complex the build is going to get.

Comment: Do you have a example of how you do that?

Comment: As Marcel points out below... http://stackoverflow.com/q/7843098/260424 has examples.

Answer (score 1):

Ahmed gave the right answer. This question has been asked before, for more info: [Is there a way to pass ant variables to java code (android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7843098/260424)